# Program execution different in Code::Blocks and remote linux server

Tags: c++, linux, g++

So I have this code:

```
using namespace std;
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "JugadorEscacs.h"

void inserirOrdenat(list<JugadorEscacs> &l, JugadorEscacs jug) {
    bool inserit=false;
    list<JugadorEscacs>::iterator itt=l.begin();
    while(itt!=l.end() && !inserit) {
        if(itt->getElo()>jug.getElo()) itt++;
        else {
            l.insert(itt,jug);
            inserit=true;
        }
    }
   if(itt==l.end()) l.push_back(jug);
}

int main () {
    list<JugadorEscacs> l;
    string nom, cognom, pais;
    int elo;

    getline(cin, nom);
    while(nom!="FI") {
        getline(cin, cognom);
        getline(cin, pais);
        cin >> elo;
        cin.ignore();
        JugadorEscacs jug(nom, cognom, pais, elo);
        if(l.empty()) l.push_front(jug);
        else inserirOrdenat(l, jug);
        getline(cin, nom);
    }
    list<JugadorEscacs>::iterator it=l.begin();
    while(it!=l.end()) {
        cout << it->getNom() << endl;
        cout << it->getCognoms() << endl;
        cout << it->getPais() << endl;
        cout << it->getElo() << endl;
        it++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The .cpp and .h are correct. When I run it on my PC using code blocks it works perfectly, but when I run it using PuTTy to connect to a linux server nothing happens. I compile it using `g++ main.cpp JugadorEscacs.cpp -o main` and I use a .txt to enter everything. The .txt is in the same directory as the main but when I run it using `./main <test1.txt` nothing happens, it returns back to the command prompt.
I don't know how to explain it in a better way, can anyone give me a hand with this?
Thanks

Comment: it 'finishes' and returns back to the command prompt.

Comment: I'm not sure, would you convert your text file by `dos2unix test1.txt test2.txt` and run your app with `test2.txt` ?

Comment: I did that, but still nothing happens. Any other ideas? :/

Comment: An easy way to find the problem is, put some `cout<<__LINE__<<endl;` somewhere between your lines and see after what line it exits.

Comment: I've done that and i've noticed that i get an endless loop reading the first group of data from the file. The first line in the file is commented, how can i ignore the first line and start reading from the second?

Comment: Hi. If it "returns" back to command prompt, how had you detected endless loop? That sounds a tad weird to me. Could you please elaborate?